# Price comparison sites and its effect on Google ranking

Tags: seo, google, backlinks, ranking, comparison

I am the webmaster of a website that contains roughly 10,000 products. I would be possibly interested to index those products in a price comparison site like PriceGrabber, Nextag, Shopbot, etc.

The principle of price comparison sites is great for an actual user that want to compare prices but my main concern is the effect it could have on my actual ranking on Google...

Since a site like Shopbot uses a CPC model (Cost-per-click), all the links on the website are built to track clicks (IE: http://www.shopbot.ca/r.html?i=3&catc=2&refshop=5706&refshopcodeid=42587349), it uses redirection, no direct links (So no direct backlinking).

Is this a smart move  SEO-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering how common practice this is, I don't foresee a problem. Google - in spite of what we like to believe sometimes - is not just a computer with a fancy algorithm, there are people behind it, checking sites manually. They do this to A) ensure that the algorithms are in fact working and B) to find "types of" pages. Price Comparison pages, for instance.

So even though a search bot might see a price comparison site as a link forest, it knows that it isn't. That's my answer to what I **think** you wish to know.

If you want to know whether you'll receive some 'Google juice' from the site, the answer is no. First, because of what you've already stated: No direct backlinks. Second however, for what I've just said above; Google knows you've paid for the links.

Hopefully that answers your question? :)

Comment: @Jivago Glad I could help.